# Android Eclipse equivalent to Xcode's xscroll and yscroll?

Tags: xcode, eclipse, android-emulator, scroll, android-webview

Are there variables equivalent to Xcode's xScroll and yScroll on Eclipse for the Android emulator?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the scroll position by calling getScrollX() . You will need a ScrollView of course.

Comment: how do i set their values tho?

Comment: You can set the scroll position like this: scrollTo(x,y);